# Inequality for Poisson point process

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm looking at Achim Klenke's *Probability Theory* book, and in the section where he introduces Poisson point processes. He does so by introducing, for intervals, a random variable $N_I$ which counts the number of events occurring during this interval, subject to the following conditions:

- be random and independent for disjoint intervals
- be homogeneous in time (the distribution depends only on the length of the interval considered)
- have finite expectation
- have no double points - at any moment only 1 event occurs

He then describes how one would formalize this as a random variable $N(t)$, which counts the number of events occurring in $(0,t]$ (he likens this to a gieger counter).

The last bullet is formalized as:
$$\lim\sup_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\epsilon P(t\in (0,\epsilon]:N(t)\geq 2)=0$$

For $P$ a probability measure. This is fine, and makes sense to me, but he follows this with a computation justifying this. The first part of it is this:

Let $P_{\epsilon}=P(t\in (0,\epsilon]:N(t)\geq 2)$.

He states that the following inequality holds $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon>0$: $$P(t\in(0,2^{-n}]:N(t)\geq 2)\geq \lfloor\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor P_{\epsilon}-\left(\lfloor\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor P_{\epsilon}\right)^2$$

It's this inequality that I'm confused as to how he arrived at, and would appreciate help in understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out, I'll just leave this here for posterity.

The case $\epsilon>2^{-n}$ is trivial, so assume $\epsilon<2^{-n}$. Divide the interval $(0,2^{-n}]$ into $N=\lfloor \frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor$ disjoint intervals of length $\epsilon$ called $I_k$, $1\leq k \leq N$. Let $A_k$ be the event that $N(t)\geq2$ for $t\in I_k$. Then, by inclusion,exclusion, we have 
\begin{align*}P(t\in(0,2^{-n}]:N(t)\geq2)\geq P(\cup_{k=1}^N A_k) &\geq \sum_{k=1}^N P(A_k)-\sum_{l,m}P(A_l\cap A_m)\\&= NP_{\epsilon}-N^2P_{\epsilon}^2\end{align*}

Since each interval is length $\epsilon$ and $N$ is homogeneous in time $P(A_k)=P_{\epsilon}$, and since each interval is disjoint, the $A_k$ are mutually independent, so $P(A_l\cap A_m)=P(A_l)P(A_m)=P_{\epsilon}^2$, and there are $N^2$ possible terms in the sum. Moreover, the inequality is justified by the Bonferroni inequalities, so it holds.